# How Block UI until page load with wait image using javascript/CSS only

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to block html page until it loads completely with wait image by javascript or CSS but **WITHOUT JQUERY**

I want to achieve like these demos http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos

**Please don't suggest with jquery solutions**.

```
HTML code:

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script>
            var ld = (document.all);
            var ns4 = document.layers;
            var ns6 = document.getElementById && !document.all;
            var ie4 = document.all;
            if (ns4)
                ld = document.loading;
            else if (ns6)
                ld = document.getElementById("loading").style;
            else if (ie4)
                ld = document.all.loading.style;
            function init() {
                if (ns4) { ld.visibility = "hidden"; }
                else if (ns6 || ie4) ld.display = "none";
            }
     </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
//image which has size of 40 mb.
            <img src="show.jpg" />
        <div id="loading" style="position:absolute; width:100%; text-align:center; top:300px;">           

            //loading image to see while loading background image
        <img src="loading.gif" />
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You should use feature detection instead of browser detection. And do you really want to support such old browsers?

Comment: Are you sure that `<img src="show.jpg" />` should be inside of `#loading` ?

Comment: <img src="show.jpg" /> is outside of loading. I have edited please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution that will show the *wait image*  when *js*  is active, and keep the *wait image* hidden if *js*  is not active:

- Create a default rule that hides the `#loading` and a `.is-loading #loading` that shows the wait image
- Use JS to add the class `wait image` to the `html` element
- When the content (or image) is loaded remove the `is-loading` class.

---

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <title></title>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     (function() {
       var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
       html.className += ' is-loading'; 

       window.onload = function() {
         html.className = String(html.className).replace('is-loading','');
       }
     }());
     </script>

     <style>
     #loading {
       display : none;
       position : absolute;
       width : 100%;
       text-align : center;
       top : 300px;
     }

     .is-loading #loading {
       display: block;
     }
     </style>


 </head>
 <body>
     <!--image which has size of 40 mb. -->
     <img src="show.jpg" >

     <div id="loading">
         <!-- loading image to see while loading background image -->
         <img src="loading.gif" >
     </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```